# The camera crops the photos

Tags: android, android-camera

My problem is that the built-in camera in my app is cropping all photos taken by itself.
For comparison:

[image: The first]

(the first photo is screenshot of camera preview, second - captured photo),

**and same camera preview is smaller than normal camera preview.. Why?**

Code:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }

        if (mPreviewSize!=null) {
            float ratio;
            if(mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)
                ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
            else
                ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;

            // One of these methods should be used, second method squishes preview slightly
            setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
            //        setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * ratio), height);
        }
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }
```

And if it is important here is GalleryFragment code:

```
// To create bitmap squared
    private Bitmap processImage(byte[] data) throws IOException {
        // Determine the width/height of the image
        int width = camera.getParameters().getPictureSize().width;
        int height = camera.getParameters().getPictureSize().height;

        // Load the bitmap from the byte array
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);

        // Rotate and crop the image into a square
        int croppedWidth = (width > height) ? height : width;
        int croppedHeight = (width > height) ? height : width;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, croppedWidth, croppedHeight, matrix, true);
        bitmap.recycle();

        // Scale down to the output size
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(cropped, 800, 800, true);
        cropped.recycle();


        return scaledBitmap;
    }

private Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Saving a bitmap to file");

            File pictureFile = cameraPreview.getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
                Log.i(TAG, "Stop saving a bitmap to file");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            PictureData.notifyMediaScannerService(getContext(), pictureFile.getPath());

            try {
                Uri uri = Converter.getImageUri(getContext(), processImage(data));
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PictureViewActivity.class)
                        .putExtra("Uri", uri.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
```

Feedback please, have a nice evening

Comment: `(The first photo is screenshot of camera preview..` Really? You hace a square screen?

Comment: Yes, it is square camera preview